# Send data from radar gun to raspberry pi (Python Scripted)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

So I am trying to get the speed from the hot wheels radar gun or any radar gun for that matter into RPI using python.. first is this possible? Second how would one go about this? My other option is building my own radar using a doppler sensor or something like that.. That would be ideal as I would have full control over the build..

What would you guys recommend?

FYI I am using this for a baseball pitching backstop that I built for my son which has sensors to detect balls and strikes utilizing python and RPI. Would just like to incorporate speed...

Comment: Without knowing anything about the circuitry involved, it's hard to say. But why not? Anyway, your question - although interesting - is too broad and off-topic for this programming Q&A site. I think [the Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit. Take the gun apart and post a few pictures of the circuit over there and I'm sure you'll get some interesting answers.

Comment: Thanks, ya I posted to RPI's site as well but figured I have always had great responses on here I would give it a shot..

Comment: Maybe you will like this article? http://blog.durablescope.com/2015/03/build-speed-camera-and-traffic-logger.html

Comment: @RyanD Did you see [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/speed-detector-for-amateur-sports-such-as-athletics-or-tennis/1577#1577)? Btw. I can't find  your question on the Raspi site. Mind dropping a link?

Comment: Link to rpi forum- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=145184&e=0

Comment: @RyanD Ah okay, I thought you meant [Stack Exchange's Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). That explains why I couldn't find it!

Comment: Hmm wasnt aware of a SA rpi site? Shoot i guess i should of posted this there...